# Javascript which opens 2 links seperately

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get my "button" to open link 1 on first click and then link 2 on second click using javascript. So just to give an example. User comes to my website, clicks button named "here", it opens up url 1. He comes back to my website, clicks the same button again, but now it opens url 2.

This is my current code which obviously opens the same url always:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function aClick() {
            window.open('https://attacomsian.com', '_blank');
        }
    </script>
```

Is there any option to modify it?

Comment: I guess you can just use a variable and an if statement. For example : ` let count = 0; function aClick() {count++; if(count<2){window.open('https://attacomsian.com', '_blank');}else{window.open('https://attacomsian2.com', '_blank');}  }

Comment: By "comes back" do you mean after the tab/browser may have been closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one example that uses [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Comments are included to explain the approach.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skdogwnv/)

```
function aClick() {
    // Since the URL will change on button click #2, we use 'let' keyword.
    let url = 'https://google.com';

    // url2 never changes so we use 'const'.
    const url2 = 'https://duckduckgo.com';

    // This variable is a boolean that determines which URL to use. We save
    // the value of the user's state in localStorage.
    const isFirstUrl = localStorage.getItem('isFirstUrl') === null;

    // If this is the first time clicking the button, we need to update the
    // localStorage for next time to use the second URL.
    if (isFirstUrl) {
        localStorage.setItem('isFirstUrl', false);
    }

    // If the value of "isFirstUrl" is false, this means we've already clicked
    // the button one time. Now, we replace the first URL with the second URL.
    if (!isFirstUrl) {
        url = url2;
    }

    // Open the new URL.
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```